# Display avatar of user profile when logged in

Tags: avatar

I am trying to display user's avatar/profile image when logged in, but when I use this:

```
 <?php
    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();     
    echo get_avatar( $current_user->ID, 64 );
```

?>

it displays the default_avatar_male.jpg, but I don't want anything to be displayed unless logged in.  Thanks for all help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hey pass the current user email id in get_avatar() function if user is logged in like this

```
<?php 
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ( ($current_user instanceof WP_User) ) {
        echo 'Welcome : ' . esc_html( $current_user->display_name );
        echo get_avatar( $current_user->ID, 32 );
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code as well and it still worked just as well as Rohil_PHPBeiginner's above.  My additional question which I posted above is how would I be able to display it like: Welcome Tom "profile image" ?

Comment: Hey Please check the above edited answer

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap this code in to a condition that **if** user is `logged in` then show **profile pic** and for that you can use wordpress function [`is_user_logged_in`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in).

So your **code** will be something like this :

```
<?php
    global $current_user;
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ):
        get_currentuserinfo();     
        echo get_avatar( $current_user->ID, 64 );
    endif;  
?>
```

Comment: Great! this worked well.  How would I be able to display user's first name, or say like: Welcome Tom "profile image"  ? Thanks again.

Comment: You can use [`wp_get_current_user`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user#Examples).